# kotlin how to make a map (MutableMap<Long, List<Object>>)

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
val group: MutableMap<String, List<Person>> =  mutableMapOf()
```

**Here is original list:**

Person(id=1, country="US")

Person(id=2, country="US")

Person(id=3, country="CA")

**Result: (want to map by country)**

group: Map<String, List> = {"US", listOf(Person(id=1, country="US"), Person(id=2, country = "US")), {"CA", listOf(Person(id=3, country "CA")}

**How can I make it?**

Comment: Why is the key type `Long` if you want to map by country? Countries are not `Long`s.

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake.. I modified it

Comment: `theList.groupByTo(group) { it.country }`. If you're fine with having a `Map` instead of `MutableMap`, then you could do `val group = theList.groupBy { it.country }`

Comment: thank you Slaw ! it's getting work!